# How to pass array of locationId to service getLocationData?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular7, angular-resource

**How to pass array of locationId to service  ?**

I have array of locations Id

```
locationArr=[40871, 60009, 38149, 40868, 43240, 15299, 53897, 40976, 38151, 23183, 38152, 78579, 23180, 40977, 23176, 39565, 40884, 15298, 38147, 40966, 39669]
```

**Actually I need to pass locationArr to http://192.168.7.45:9200/location/_doc/+locationArr**

I need to pass array of  locationId exist on locationArr  to service to get GPS1 latitude and longitude for every locationId on array locationArr.

service get location by locationId for only one locationId but for array of location this is my question

```
getLocationData(id: number) {  
console.log("server "+id)  
return this.http.get('http://192.168.7.45:9200/location/_doc/'+id);  
}
```

so please How to achieve it by loop within array of location

```
calling service
this.partDetailsService.getLocationData(this.LocationId).subscribe(res => {          
         this.dataLocation = res['_source']['GPS1'];     
         var loc = this.dataLocation.split(',');      
         this.lat = loc[0].trim();    
         this.lng = loc[1].trim();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your back-end needs to be changed to accept multiple locationId, seems it's only accepting one, then based on that you can send your data.

If your back-end will support multiple Ids as comma separated values in GET then your angular code will be like below

```
getLocationData(ids: Array<number>) {  
   console.log("server "+ids)  
   return this.http.get('http://192.168.7.45:9200/location/_doc/'+ids.join(','));  
}
```

If your back-end will supports multiple Ids as an array of POST body then your angular code will be like below

```
getLocationData(ids: Array<number>) {  
   console.log("server "+ids)  
   return this.http.post('http://192.168.7.45:9200/location/_doc/', { ids: ids });  
}
```

If your back-end doesn't support multiple Ids, then you need to loop through ids and call the backend for each

```
getLocationData(ids: Array<number>) {  
    let observableBatch = [];

    this.ids.forEach((id) => {

        observableBatch.push(
              this.http.get('http://192.168.7.45:9200/location/_doc/'+id)
                       .map((res) => res.json()));
    });

    return Observable.forkJoin(observableBatch);
}


this.partDetailsService.getLocationData(this.LocationIds).subscribe(res : Array<any> => {  
         since it's an array you needs to loop through res        
         res.forEach((item, index) => {
            const dataLocation = res[index]['_source']['GPS1'];     
            const loc = this.dataLocation.split(',');      
            this.lat[index] = loc[0].trim();    
            this.lng[index] = loc[1].trim();
         });
}
```

All in all, back-end api signature drives how to call it

Comment: i need to achieve it by front end so can i do that by using arrays of request and using fork join can you help me in that

Comment: if your backend doesn't support multipleIds, you need to call it in a loop

Comment: can you help me how to loop within array of locations

Comment: and how to call it inside component to get latitude and longitude this.partDetailsService.getLocationData(this.LocationId).subscribe(res => {          
         this.dataLocation = res['_source']['GPS1'];     
         var loc = this.dataLocation.split(',');      
         this.lat = loc[0].trim();    
         this.lng = loc[1].trim();

Comment: @ahmedbarbary you will receive an array, so you need to loop through it

Comment: if i need to show loc[0]  and loc[1] without using variable lat and lng then what will be loc[index][0] or this is wrong

Comment: console.log(loc[index][0]) console.log(loc[index][1]) are this correct when i need to display values without variables

Comment: can you please add variable after loop do as accumlation varaible to latitude and longtude both  accumlationvariable=[52,60], [30,40]  etc